# batch file to run a sequence of tasks

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have hundreds of swfs I want to convert to mp4s using a program called Swivel. The problem is that there is no option to bulk convert, so I'm trying to write a batch script. I'm very clueless so please forgive blunders.
I have this so far

```
@echo off
"C:\Users\me\Desktop\Swivel - Shortcut.lnk" C:\Users\me\Documents\swfs\fluent_5_5.swf
```

This opens and converts one swf. Is there a way of writing the script so that it would convert all swfs in a given folder one after the other?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%a in (C:\Users\me\Documents\swfs\*swf) do "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Swivel - Shortcut.lnk" %%a
```

should apply each matching filename to `%%a`